# Can geom_point can locate on geom_boxplot sperated by 'fill' in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

There are two data.frame: one is for geom_point and the other is for geom_boxplot

The data is follows:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tuBJW94OtZBjww2tlpMbQDyKLmKQcy9n/view?usp=share_link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lgtdrioEb_SaGRVjqKFTUb6FPKy7r-Tf/view?usp=share_link

I can make the plot as follow:

[image]

But I want to have the figure like this one:

[image]

The code of the first plot:

```
library("ggplot2")

IGFpercent_P <- read.csv(IGFpercent_P)
deter_P <- read.csv(deter_P)

IGFpercent_P$catchment <- 
  factor(IGFpercent_P$catchment,levels=c("dragon","flat","nei","jem","peak"))

ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(data=IGFpercent_P,aes(x = catchment, y = percentage, fill = period),outlier.shape = NA)+
  geom_point(data=deter_P,aes(x=catchment, y=percentage),shape = 4,colour = "red")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_text(size=13, color="black"),
    axis.text = element_text(size=13, color="black"))
```

How should I modify it to become the second figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the points positions as `position_dodge` and provide the grouping aesthetic.

```
library(tidyverse)
IGFpercent_P <- read.csv('IGFpercent_P.csv')
deter_P <- read.csv('deter_P.csv')

IGFpercent_P$catchment <- 
  factor(IGFpercent_P$catchment,levels=c("dragon","flat","nei","jem","peak"))

ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(data=IGFpercent_P,
               aes(x = catchment, y = percentage, fill = period),outlier.shape = NA)+
  geom_point(data=deter_P,aes(x=catchment, y=percentage, group = period),
             shape = 4,colour = "red", 
             position = position_dodge(width=0.75))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_text(size=13, color="black"),
    axis.text = element_text(size=13, color="black"))
```

[image]